# jQuery won't detect when an option is selected

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to manipulate a select list with jQuery but it won't detect when an option is selected.

My select list:

```
<select id="SelThreeSEL" class="selectListComponent" component="selectListComponent"  multiple="true" size="5">
<option value="1"> Random Value 1 </option>
<option value="2"> Random Value 2 </option>
</select>
```

I'm using a simple change function to verify if it detects an option when selected and it won't even display an alert.

Test code:

```
// Getting values when item is selected
$("#SelThreeSEL").change(function() {
alert($(this).val());
alert($(this).children("option:selected").text());
});
```

When trying to manipulate the list (move items up/down) with:

```
function moveUpItem(){
$('#SelThreeSEL option:selected').each(function(){
$(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
});
```

I get a $('#SelThreeSEL option:selected') is null.

Could the issue be that my select displays 5 items?

I've verified that jQuery works on the page with a simple $('div').click() function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on your usage you may want to try,   .bind('change', function() {})

I have had problems in the past where the shortcut, .change, did not have the same behavior for whatever reason.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cyF7k/1/) here is my test code,it seems to be alright.

Comment: Thanks. I now see the code should work fine. I don't know what's causing a conflict with select lists.

Answer (score 0):

Change your moveUpItem() function as follows:

```
    function moveUpItem(){
       $('#SelThreeSEL').find("option:selected").each(function(){
       $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/qLMyk/

HTML:

```
<select id="selList" multiple="true" size="4">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
    <option>Option 6</option>
    <option>Option 7</option>
</select>
<button id="moveUp">Move Up</button>
<button id="moveDown">Move Down</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#selList').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});

$('#moveUp').click(function(){
    $('#selList option:selected')
        .each(function(i, item)
        {
            var $item = $(item);
            $item.prev().before($item);
        }); 
});

$('#moveDown').click(function(){
    $('#selList option:selected')
        .each(function(i, item)
        {
            var $item = $(item);
            $item.next().after($item);
        }); 
});
```

Comment: Not working. I'm guessing the page is having conflict with jquery.